# Why/how is the Reality Stone an actual stone now, instead of a liquid?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thor-the-dark-world

About a week ago I came across a Marvel magazine that was a special edition specifically for *Avengers: Infinity War*. It provides the history of each Infinity Stone in the MCU up to *Infinity War*, has interviews the actors, etc..

## Anyway..

when it talks about the Reality Stone, it says the following:

> The Reality Stone is unique, even by the standards of the Infinity Stones, in that **it is not really a stone, but is in fact, a red, viscous liquid**. There are, however, special theories that state that at one time, long ago, it was actually a stone, just like the others.

..

> **The [Reality Stone] seeks out a host body and will draw strength from its life force, eventually killing the host**. Lesser beings will sicken and die if exposed to it for long. But Malekith was a strong host, so it enhanced his strength, giving him the power to fight Thor on an equal basis.

## If this is true, then, how is the Reality Stone actually a stone now, and able to be seated in Thanos's gauntlet like all the others?

Per the events of *Thor: Dark World*, and of the provided passage from Marvel themselves, the Reality Stone isn't really a stone, and, it has the behavior of "infecting" a host, just as it did to Jane Foster and Malekith.

## So, why didn't it do this to Thanos?

---

Clip of Malekith extracting the Aether from Jane Foster's body, and accepting it into his:

Thanos using the Reality Stone and it seated in the Gauntlet, just like the others stones:

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the second picture from? That's not the order of the stones in the actual film (time stone is on the thumb, space and power stones are next to each other, for example).

Comment: @Kitkat Oh, right. That was from before the film's release.. I've edited to include clip from film, and a screenshot.

Comment: Power stone didn't disintegrated him or Tesseract didn't made him into a stonekeeper, he is special

Comment: @AnkitSharma Thanks for the comment, but that's not quite what's being asked here.. specifically asking why the Reality Stone is now a stone instead of a liquid, like the last time we saw it, and like Marvel themselves describe. With that, comes the behavior of infecting a host, etc..

Comment: @Charles I know that, I am just adding that Thanos seems to be a special guy because he seems to be touching every stone easily without any side effect and for reality stone MCU never show how he achieved it. Maybe a prelude comics on the way or we might never know

Comment: Found the one I was thinking of, actually. It's not an explicit statement but whatever: [Is Aether really an Infinity Stone?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173657/is-aether-really-an-infinity-stone). Also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/158039/2171

Comment: @JAB Ehh.. the response in the second (more relevant) link you provide is complete conjecture. See my comment on that post for reasoning against the selected answer. As for the first list, the plot line of the Infinity Stones was still being developed in *Thor: Ragnarok*, and so, that question is about if "the Aether" is referring to an Infinity Stone, since it hadn't been associated with the Reality Stone yet.

Comment: Why would a reality-altering liquid not be able to behave unlike typical liquids?

Comment: Technically it's a sort of angry sludge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The stone may manifest itself as liquid in most cases but the gauntlet was specifically designed to wield it like all the other stones.

It's not difficult to assume that the liquid form is part of the reality stone's power, to take different forms. Perhaps holding the gauntlet near it is enough to attract it to compress into place in the form of a stone, like it appears to attract the other stones like a magnet when it's near them. Notice how Thanos snaps them into place, it seems that the gauntlet is drawing them in.

Since this all happened off-screen we can't really know, but I see no reason for this not to be the case for someone wearing the gauntlet.

Answer (score 0):

The "Stone" is A STONE! The dark elves turned it into "Aether" (or liquid) for their "universal takeover plan". But they were stopped before it could be used how they intended!

Once Thanos got to the Collector, he turned the Aether back into the stone's original form, so it could be placed into the gauntlet.

The stone IS NOT LIQUID! It was simply changed temporarily.

Comment: Hi John, it would be great if you could back this up with some sources. Welcome to Movies & TV!